# ComboBox not present in TK

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

According to the docs there should be a `ComboBox` operation in TK, but I can't find it. `dir(tk)` shows

> ['ACTIVE', 'ALL', 'ANCHOR', 'ARC', 'At', 'AtEnd', 'AtInsert', 'AtSelFirst', 'AtSelLast', 'BASELINE', 'BEVEL', 'BOTH', 'BOTTOM', 'BROWSE', 'BUTT', 'BaseWidget', 'BitmapImage', 'BooleanType', 'BooleanVar', 'BufferType', 'BuiltinFunctionType', 'BuiltinMethodType', 'Button', 'CASCADE', 'CENTER', 'CHAR', 'CHECKBUTTON', 'CHORD', 'COMMAND', 'CURRENT', 'CallWrapper', 'Canvas', 'Checkbutton', 'ClassType', 'CodeType', 'ComplexType', 'DISABLED', ...

The version is

```
import Tkinter as tk
tk.__version__
```

> '$Revision: 81008 $'

on my Mac (latest OS X 10.11.6). No brewery for python whatsoever.

Comment: According to which docs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `ComboBox` widget in `tkinter`, what you are looking for is `tkinter.ttk` (in Python 3, in Python 2 it's just called `ttk`), which provides themed tk widgets. [Docs for `tkinter.ttk`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html), and [subsection for ComboBox](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Combobox).

You can use this code to import ttk and use its widgets rather than standard `tkinter` ones (note the different capitalization between 2 and 3!):

Python 2

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
```

Python 3:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

Comment: I also made the mistake of using a lowercase C for Combobox. It must be capitalized. 
This reference is lowercase. https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-combobox/

Answer (score 0):

Started to learn tkinter (on python 2.7) just now, I ran into this problem and I read the first person's reply it didnt make sense at first so I had to go through the docs.

Combobox is part of ttk

```
comboBox_example = ttk.Combobox(window, width, textvariable)
```

wont work and will throw an error but if you give the library an alias

```
import ttk as TTK
```

or something, then

```
comboBox_example = TTK.Combobox(window, width, textvariable)
```

will work w/o a hitch